# Java swing - wrong size

Tags: java, swing, layout, size

so I have this problem. I wrote this code in Java Eclipse SDK 4.2.1. I haven't wrote it all here, actionPerformed method is irrelevant now and it is called from Main once. The problem is sometimes when I run it, one of the components just fills the whole window and overlaps all others. I tried changing sizes by random numbers for example from 400 to 350 and sometimes it worked and then it broke again. I'm probably missing something, I just don't know what. I searched other forums, but found nothing about it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JTextField field1;
    JTextField field2;

    public Window()
    {
        super("Main Window");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Initialize();
    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
        field1 = new JTextField();
        field2 = new JTextField();
        field1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 100);
        field2.setBounds(0,100,400,100);
        add(field1);
        add(field2);
        field1.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        field1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        field2.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        field2.setForeground(Color.RED);
        JButton button = new JButton("Create");
        button.setBounds(0, 200, 400, 100);
        add(button);
        button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        button.addActionListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: *"then it broke again"*  IT was broken from the moment the code set an explicit size on the frame and bounds for the test fields.  Also, make sure the GUI is constructed on the EDT.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - *"SDK 4.2.1"*  I first read that number as '1.4.2'.  What is Java version '4.2.1'?

Comment: BTW2 - that GUI seems to be trying to put 3 components in a vertical column of equally sized cells.  Use a `GridLayout` - it is perfect for this use.

Comment: @Andrew the 4.2.1 is version of Eclipse. I'm not sure if that is somehow important, but I tried to provide as much information as possible while still relevant.

Comment: I probably misunderstood you.  Did you write this code 'recently' (within the last month)?

Comment: Yes, I'm really just starting with Java in general and haven't found the correct online tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your code does not respect the layout manager being used as you're trying to add components as if the layout being used were null when in fact it isn't. The solution is to read up on and learn about layout managers, and use them; this includes avoiding calling `setBounds(...)`. Note that a JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout by default. This information should help you get started. Also note that a ***wrong*** solution is to use a null layout. So if anyone suggests this, I urge you to ignore them.

Comment: Note that the default layout for a frame changed from `FlowLayout` to `BordeLayout`.  I mention this because 1) The user made the app. in 1.4 (not sure when the change happened) & 2) the change SNAFU'd a bunch of GUIs that had presumed the flow layout. -- This is why I generally prefer to **set** a content pane.  We get to choose the `Border` and layout - *without* those types of surprises.

Comment: I started using Java in 99 on JDK1.4 and the default was BorderLayout.

Comment: @camickr  Thanks for confirming.  I was sure it changed at one point, but can find no reference to it.  It now seems my presumption of 'compiled in 1.4' was wrong in any case.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, haven't tried it yet, since I'm not home. But I believe you're right. Do you know any online guides you would recommend a beginner like me?

Comment: @Gasert: The standard Oracle Java tutorials has a Swing section, and in that Swing section is a layout section. I don't have the link immediately on me, but can get it quickly (as can you) via Google. Luck!